# interval and radius of convergence of Maclaurin series: $(-1)^{n+1} (|(1-x)/(1+x)|-1)^n)/n$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence of the series:
$(-1)^{n+1} \frac{\bigl(\bigl|\tfrac{1-x}{1+x}\bigr|-1\bigl)^n} n$ representing the equation $\ln|(1-x)/(1+x)|$. Applying substitution to the Maclaurin series $\ln(1+x)$ gets me this. when I use the ratio test I'm given the inequality $(x<-3) \cup (-1/3<x)...$ what does this mean for a radius of convergence?

Desmos Link:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u5cn0qpz2d

Comment: What have written isn't a power series (it isn't in the form $\sum a_n(x-c)^n$ ) so the notion of radius of convergence doesn't make sense because a radius has to be from a center. If you want a power series, first use your log properties before converting.

Answer (score 1):

by the root test

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\bigl(\bigl|\tfrac{1-x}{1+x}\bigr|-1\bigl)^n} n\right|^\frac 1n < 1\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n^\frac 1n|\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|-1| < 1$

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n^\frac 1n = 1$

Which means that we only need to concern ourselves with:

$\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right| - 1| < 1$

or

$\left| \frac{1-x}{1+x}\right| < 2$

Suppose  $\frac{1-x}{1+x} > 0$ i.e. $-1 < x< 1$

$\frac{1-x}{1+x} < 2\\
-3x - 1 < 0\\
x > -\frac 13$

otherwise

$\frac{x-1}{1+x} < 2\\
\frac{-x-3}{1+x} < 0$

if $x \approx -3$ then $1+x < 0$

$-x-3 > 0\\ 
x < - 3$

We will converge when.

$x< - 3$ or $-\frac 13 < x < 1$

Now we should check the endpoints to see if these converge under closed (or half closed intervals)

If $|\frac {1-x}{1+x}|= 2, \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1^n} n$ converges

and when $x = 1, \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty (0)^n\frac{1^n} n$ converges

$x\le - 3$ or $-\frac 13 \le x \le 1$